# Align <li> elements with list-type:outside style to the content border consistently

Tags: html, css

I wonder if there exists an easy and solid way to style ul and li elements so that when using list-style: outside , the li elements lign up with the content above it, or with the content box in which it is in without margins or padding.

Condider this: ( http://jsfiddle.net/Um5L9/2/ )

```
<div id = "container1">

    <span>Something</span>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <div>One</div>
            <div>Some more text or content here</div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <div>One</div>
            <div>Some more text or content here</div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <div>One</div>
            <div>Some more text or content here</div>
        </li>

    </ul>

</div>

body {
    margin:20px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}

ul {
    list-style: square outside none;
}
```

The result will be this:

[image]

What I want is this:

[image]

And it's easy to do by just adding some padding:

```
ul {
    list-style: square outside none;
    padding-left:15px;
}
```

But there has to be a better way surely than setting pixel margins.  Maybe something that would work for all font sizes?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Just want to add that I need both children of the li to line up underneath each other

Comment: that doesn't work, it's the same as the pixel approach - not really a solid method that will work for all font sizes etc .. :(

Comment: It will work for all font sizes since `em` is based on font size.

Comment: no mate it doesnt seem to work for me http://jsfiddle.net/Um5L9/5/

Comment: Do you care about the size of the bullet as the font-size changes?

Comment: yep i think I do, otherwise I would have to go in and change the bullet size manually and that kind of defeats the purpose :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it that appears to be fairly robust and uses pseudo elements.

Apply the following CSS:

```
body {
    margin:20px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-size: 1.0em;
}
ul li {
    margin-left: 0em;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 1.0em;
}
ul li:before {
    content:"\2022";
    font-size: 1.0em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/SfGbW/

Note: Look up the ISO code for the desired list marker.

Comment: wow, this works very well from what I can see! It works perfectly with all font sizes. Thanks, Marc, I have always been looking for something like this to use globally. I hate it when the bulleted items have such a big indent, I like them without indents!

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using something like this:

```
ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Um5L9/4/

Comment: You need to fix your fiddle. It still defines the list-style-position as `outside`.

Comment: Knobbie this will work if there is only one child in the li, but not if there are two like with my example

Comment: @BigMacAttack Ah, good point, but still the second line is not indented. http://jsfiddle.net/Um5L9/4/

Comment: @Doorknob That's correct, the second line isn't indented. But it wasn't made clear in the original question that this is a problem. I feel your -1 is too critical.

Comment: I find that it was very critical too.. I am just starting to answer questions on here.. I am not perfect, but I am learning as a go Should I deleted my answer or something?

Comment: @DerrickJackson Well, the answer is wrong, so that's why I downvoted it.

Comment: @Doorknob Good point. But it is at least a solution helpful in some capacity. Even if it does requiring compromising.

Comment: @BigMacAttack Okay then, undownvoted (dummy edit so I could remove the -1)